# Storing and iterating lists in window azure cache

Tags: list, caching, azure

I am making an azure web role service, in where I have a long list (thousands) of objects, which I am filter upon different criteria. I need to cache the list, but I have concern, which is:

Suppose I have a number of role instances, and the list is cached on one machine, while another machine wants to iterate the list. Will the list be copied into the memory of the requesting machine and iterated after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Azure Caching is serialized - meaning that when you store an item to cache it is serialized (using the .Net XmlSerializer by default, but you can change this) and when it is retrieved from the cache it is deserialized to a new object.

So yes - when you retrieve a list from the cache (even on the same role instance!) you will have a new list in memory that is iterated over.

Comment: One caveat on my answer - it presumes that you are either using the Azure Cache, or that you have set up your HttpSession to use this cache http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/#store-session it is also possible to use HttpSession without enabling the azure caching - in that case you will have separate lists on each role - not good!